# page now found error each and every time in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I got the problem of not to find any page and category in wordpress.
I have complete working site in my local but on the server i not able to open any page.
from the back end when we "view" the page then alos i did not able to see the page. it cause the problem like:

`This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?

It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching, or one of the links below, can help.`

Same error i also got when i see the "Hello World" post from backend.
i dont know what happen.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: did you changes your permalink ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check [your .htaccess file](http://www.squidoo.com/wordpress-not-found-error-fix) and enable [mod_rewrite in Apache2](http://www.lavluda.com/2007/07/15/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-in-apache22-debian/).

Answer (score 0):

Check your permalink structure or just update the permalink structure and check the site again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change access to .htaccess file in your wordpress installation.
2. Enable the mod_rewrite. Follow the screen shot.

[image]

Helpful Links : http://blog.cmstutorials.org/tutorials/tips-tricks/how-to-make-mod_rewrite-work-on-wamp

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-change-permalink-structure-breaks-entire-site?replies=13